# Is there a way to create tagged unions of arrays in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to represent a heterogeneous array of arrays in TypeScript using tagged unions.

However I'm not sure if this is possible in TypeScript.

```
type Entity<K, V> = [number, K, V, number];

type All =
    | Entity<"foo", number>
    | Entity<"bar", string>
    | Entity<"baz", string[]>;

const data: All[] = [
    [1, "foo", 4, 12345],
    [2, "bar", "hello world", 12346],
    [3, "baz", ["New York", "Los Angeles"], 123457],
];

data.map((datum) => {
    const [id, attr, val, tx] = datum;
    switch (attr) {
        case "foo":
            return val + 1; // Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'string | number | string[]' and 'number'.ts(2365)
        case "bar":
            return `The following is a string: '${val}'`;
        case "baz":
            return val.join(", "); // Property 'join' does not exist on type 'string | number | string[]'. Property 'join' does not exist on type 'string'.ts(2339)
    }
});
```

TypeScript is not discriminating on the second value of the array to infer the type of the third element.

This works when represented as an array of objects, but not for arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tuple types can be constituents of a tagged union. The real lmitation that after the destructuring `[id, attr, val, tx] = datum;` typescript will not consider the destructured variables related in any way, so narrowing one does not impact others.

If you write the code using indexes the code works as expected:

```
data.map((datum) => {
    switch (datum[1]) {
        case "foo":
            return datum[2] + 1; // ✅
        case "bar":
            return `The following is a string: '${datum[2]}'`;
        case "baz":
            return datum[2].join(", "); //  ✅
    }
});
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=23&ssc=4&pln=13&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAogdsAlqAPAaQDRQGoD4oC8UA2nAK4C2ARhAE5aY5bnV0C6A3ALABQvokKAEEANiMK8oUqAB9YCZCBQAiAGYB7dcuaUatXJOlz4SVMqoBDWtqgBnYLURwA5gZ7TZ800vMWAXjb2ji7EbLjcfDwAxupw9lAAJhbAFgBcwmKhhCSGUsQAjFhqmjYALFj5AEwAzKUArGwYuSSVRZbWRQAWEGLqUADu6rQiCTZVtQBsjc3E1W3+NsTKAHIQ-VAAmkMA1jbKADLqtsIuPRC2yo1Q4-UA7NM8nLy8SSkAdBQWYAAU36+UAEpCPgAN7NWz9ZBRTpQP7JSgFNhAsHuDzSKIWWzQYpaVLNNHSWgQYBkWhwRLwijESpsKAAamuHCgAHpmVBAKDk+PRmOx7WUeNRBI8RJJZKgAAMACrdKAaXqQlxQRDHCx2BxOZzpADkABIQf8qTSAL5a8URIVQDFYqC+AICi3C4mk8kG6lsN4AK3UTm+ewBTNZUk5gqgRt4Rv9QA)